# mySQL PHPmyadmin, grabbing from multiple tables

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, group-by

Let's say I have 2 tables.  Table 1 contains 2 columns. ID_1 and ID_2.  Table 2 has 4 Columns.  Name_ID_1, Name_ID_2, Product, Amount.

What I want to do, is select Name_ID_1, Name_ID_2, Product, sum( Amount ) from Table 2 where Name_ID_1 is = to Table 1.ID_1 in my current table, Table 2.

The end result I want is the sum of Amount per Product per Name_ID_2 where Table 2's Name_ID_1 = Table 1.ID_1.  The code below is returning 0 results.

```
SELECT `Product`,`Name_ID_2`,`Name_ID_1`, sum( `Amount` ) 
FROM Table 2 
WHERE 'Name_ID_1' = 'Table 1.ID_1'
GROUP BY `Name_ID_2`
```

End results desired look like this...

```
Corn|JIM|Corn Company|100

Soy|JIM|Soy Company|200

Corn|Jack|Corn Company|100

Soy|Jack|Soy Company|100
```

Comment: look in to sql `join`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT `Product`,`Name_ID_2`,`Name_ID_1`, sum( `Amount` ) as Amount
FROM Table2 inner join Table1 on `Table2`.`Name_ID_1` = `Table1`.`ID_1`
GROUP BY `Name_ID_2`
```